# Create Polly Retry Policy for Synchronous web api call c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, polly

I have implemented the below Polly Policies for the HttpClient.

```
IHostBuilder hostBuilder = new HostBuilder().ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                                   {
                                       AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
                                       IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
                                       configuration.Bind("Configuration", appSettings);

                                    services.AddSingleton(appSettings);                                          services.AddHttpClient("WebAPI", client =>
                                       {
                                           client.BaseAddress = new Uri(appSettings.WebApiBaseAddress);
                                           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                                       })
                                       .AddPolicyHandler(HttpClientPolicyHandler.WaitAndRetry(appSettings.RetryCount))
                                       .AddPolicyHandler(HttpClientPolicyHandler.Timeout(appSettings.TimeOut));

                                       services.AddHostedService<RDPersister>();
                                   });

        await hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();

public static class HttpClientPolicyHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a Wait and Retry policy for HttpClient on the basis of specified Status Code and Timeout.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="retryCount">Number of retries.</param>
    /// <returns>Wait and Retry policy handler.</returns>
    public static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> WaitAndRetry(int retryCount)
    {
        return HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
               .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
               .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
               .Or<HttpRequestException>()
               .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a Timeout policy for HttpClient.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="seconds">Timeout.</param>
    /// <returns>Timeout policy handler.</returns>
    public static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> Timeout(int seconds)
    {
        return Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
    }
}
```

Below is the asynchronous call of the web api

```
private async void CallWebApi(string webApiJsonMessage)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("WebAPI");
            string uri = "api/CalculateOrder";

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(webApiJsonMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        string token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {          
            }
            else
            {
            }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _logger.Error($"Exception occurred while calling WebAPI: {ex.Message} for message : {webApiJsonMessage}");
     }
 }
```

But I want to create a synchronous call to WebAPI since I want to wait for the response to come.
My question then in that case do I need to create sync policy in Polly and how??

And one more question the timeout policy will work for the entire retries. Do I need to create one more policy for single retry timeout as well?

Any help??

Comment: @John: This is more in respect to Polly and its sync policy with combination to sync calling of web api. But the question u have mentioned its just how to make Sync calling.

Comment: I've reopened your question, but I wonder why you want to make async code (the http request) sync. Can you explain your motivation? I ask because if you make `CallWebApi` an `async Task`, you can `await` it to get the response.

Comment: @John: We usually received too many messages to the application which is calling this WebApi. We actually then end up sending too many calls to the web API which became the problem.

Comment: Regarding timeout-for-whole-operation versus timeout-per-try with HttpClientFactory, this is [documented in the Polly + HttpClientFactory documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#use-case-applying-timeouts)

Comment: As others say, using `await` with async (as already in the code posted in the q) does wait for the response to come.  Changing to sync (other factors being equal) will not improve this; it will consume more resources in your caller (it will block calling threads). You could consider other ways of limiting throughput, such as serial rate-limiting, or parallelism throttling such as with Polly [Bulkhead policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead).

Comment: So just to be 100% certain: you have tried changing `async void CallWebApi` to `async Task CallWebApi` and used an async Polly policy, which you have awaited, and it hasn't worked for you? That's certainly what I'd do, anyway. As indicated by the question I previously marked yours as a duplicate of, you can't wait for `async void` because it doesn't return a `Task`. I think this is a good reason why you might be having this problem.

Comment: +1 to what John said (I missed the `async void`).  For clarity: you can't `await` an `async void`; a call to an `async void` will return before the result is available.  If you simply change to `async Task CallWebApi(...)` then a call `await CallWebApi(...)` (whether through a Polly policy or not) will wait for the response to come.